# How to change elements attribute from iframe element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to get set the height of the div from inside of my `iframe`.

I have something like

```
<div id='test' style='height:150px;'>some stuff..</div>

<iframe id="test" src="http://www.myproject.com frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
   <title>test project</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="g_reset.css">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="options.js"></script>
   </head>
   bunch of html...
   <a id='click' href='#'>click<a/>
</iframe>
```

I want to be able to change the 'test' div height when I click 'click' inside my `iframe`.

in my `options.js` I have..

```
$('#click).click(function(){
   alert('pop')
   $('#test').attr('height','500');
})
```

Alert will pop but it doesn't seem to change the height of the `div`. Can anyone help me about the issue? thanks a lot!

Comment: Is the iframe loaded from the same domain/port/protocol as the main window that implements the iframe?

Comment: @StevenV yes. it is in the same domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a jQuery solution, you can use something like this within your iframe.

```
$('#test', window.parent.document).css('height', '500px');
```

or

```
$(window.parent.document).find('#test').css('height', '500px');
```

For the first example, the second parameter in the `$()` is the context to search within. Also notice I used `css()` instead of `attr()` since you're trying to modify the styles of element, instead of an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:D

```
<a id='click' href='#' onClick='parent.document.getElementById(\"test\").style.height=\"50px\"'>click<a/>
```